# Fourier Optics: Far Field Image

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

I have a question about computing the far field diffraction pattern of a laser beam:

If $L_{1}$ is large enough, then at $z=L_{1}$ we see the Fourier transform of the input $f(x, y)$. If $L_{2}$ is large enough, we see the Fourier transform of the input image at $z=L_{1}$ (the Fourier transform ${\cal F}$ of
$f(x,y)$). Since ${\cal F}\{{\cal F}\{f(x,y)\}\}=f(-x, -y)$, we should observe the original image at $z=L_{1}+L_{2}$. Is the above claim true or false?

My intuition says that this claim is false either since the Fourier transform is not shift invariant or because the input for the second stage is not a plane wave, but I'm unsure how to express this rigorously.

Comment: I mean what even is $L_1$? A lens? What is $L_2$?

Comment: It's a limit process. So for $z\rightarrow \infty$ the fact that one can approximate the diffraction process by a Fourier transform becomes more exact. So it would not make sense to try and do it twice.

Comment: It's hard to address this question because there's a lot you haven't told us.  What is $L_1$ and $L_2$?   What is $f(x,y)$ ?   Is it the amplitude distribution of a laser beam?  Is it the transmission of an aperture?  Does your use of the word "laser beam" mean that you are particularly interested in a Gaussian beam?  When you "see" the FT, you see only the squared amplitude; phase information is lost.  Do you mean to take the FT of the distribution of amplitude (if it were possible to have it) on a plane?  That misses the point that the FT appears in $\vec{k}$ space, not real space.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because the far-field Fraunhofer diffraction pattern is not an exact Fourier transform but rather just proportional to a Fourier transform. Part of this proportionality is a phase factor which depends on the coordinates in the plane at $z$, and if you wanted to do another Fourier transform you would have to take this into account. The reason we usually ignore it is because we normally only care about the intensity which is independent of the phase.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Fraunhofer diffraction integral and let z = L1, the resulting pattern is a Fourier transform of the input. Instead, if you use the Fraunhofer diffraction integral and let z = L1 + L2, the resulting pattern is still a Fourier transform of the input, but broader. Adding distance never introduces a second Fourier transform.